# Jenkins not recognizing classes in a module

Tags: python, jenkins, statsd

I am using Jenkins to build my projects. 
I have a docker container to run my service. I build my container images and then start the service and let container running on my host.
In the container I am installing a statsd plugin and looks to me that the plugin is being installed correctly by the following lines in Jenkins docker image build

```
Downloading/unpacking statsd==3.1 (from volmgr==1.0)
Downloading statsd-3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

But when i run the container image, it fails with the following message

```
from statsd import StatsClient
ImportError: cannot import name StatsClient
```

On my local setup the same code works fine and I do not get any import errors.

This is the link for getting the tar file for statsd which shows that it has StatsClient in it(the class I am getting an import error on)
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/statsd
Can anyone help me why this is happening ?

Answer (score 0):

Put lines into your Jenkins build script that print out the directory tree. Look to see if the statsd package was installed, and where.

Print the environment inside the builder. Check PYTHONPATH.